# Scrolling in Question view is buggy if the scroll event begins inside the text area

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I originally thought this had to do with third-party keyboards, but later realized that it's purely about where I begin to touch my display when I try to scroll. If I try to scroll by first touching in the text area, then scrolling doesn't always happen, but if I try to scroll by first touching in the suggested questions area, then scrolling works every time.

- App Version: 1.5.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6s Plus
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Comment: What exact issue are you having?  Are you not able to scroll into the tags section?  I'm trying with the Google Keyboard and I can still scroll to the tags field after its been obscured by the keyboard.

Comment: @BrianNickel I did some more testing and it seems that the issue is around scrolling sometimes working and sometimes not working. I used to have this same issue in Google Hangouts a long time ago. When I try to scroll by beginning to touch inside the text area it gives me problems, but when I try to scroll by beginning to touch in the suggested questions area, it works every time. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  If I quickly swipe or swipe before it switches to select mode, it scrolls.  If I tap and hold too long it doesn't scroll but the selection loupe is clearly visible.

Comment: @BrianNickel How can I upload a video to SE to show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.3.3.

The problem is that the text view thinks it is scrollable even though it isn't.  (The text view is at full height and embedded in a scrollable view.)  I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the fact that on an Plus the top edge is aligned to 0.3333333 and there's some floating point math at play.  This is causing the text view's scroll gesture recognizer to claim ownership of the swipe gesture but doing nothing with it.

I'm now forcing the gesture recognizer to fail.

Comment:  Thanks. I wish you had been on the Google Hangouts team to fix their app when this bug was around for months.